# Xamarin Forms CarouselView and ScrollView already scrolled without visited

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, scrollview, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I have a CarouselView with inside a ScrollView .

I've seen it plastered across documentation that it's not advisable to nest a scrollview inside any other scrollable layout, but what else can I do when I need to be able to scroll between items and each item must have scrollable content also.

Now my problem is with iOS (with all version after 10+) and Android (will all version after 6+). Let's assume we have 10 items and during the first display I make a vertical scroll in the middle of the content. When I get to the fifth view it is not displayed as a new element and therefore from the top but in the middle. If I do it to the second, the sixth mirrors the second and so on. In practice it seems that the views are linked by 5 in 5.

Here is my simple code:

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" 
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"  >
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">
                        <ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" >
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Image 
                                       Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" HeightRequest="350"
                                       Aspect="AspectFill" />

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>

                                <Label Text="{Binding Details}" FontSize="35" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Details}" FontSize="35" TextColor="Aqua"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Details}" FontSize="35" TextColor="Fuchsia"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Details}" FontSize="35" TextColor="OliveDrab"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ScrollView>
                        <Label Text="Fixed Button" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

[GIF dimostration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdQax.gif)

Comment: The `CarouselView` support scrolling. Why do you want to put this `CarouselView ` inside `ScrollView`? Check the MS docs about the scrolling. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/scrolling

Comment: Without ScrollView inside CarouselView I cannot make the vertical scroll of the single view if the content is not all visible on the screen. Maybe something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i missunderstand what you want with `I have a CarouselView with inside a ScrollView .`. I make the code to test with 15 items. It works well. Please check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/SYaQRWR Could you provide more details?

Comment: The problem is related to the vertical scroll. Try a smaller device or add more labels to increase the text. At that point the first view of the carousel makes a vertical scroll, at which point go to view number 5 and you will see that it is already scrolled vertically.

Comment: Could you give a screenshot like gif?

Comment: https://gifyu.com/image/YPND the first view I scroll it at the end. When I go to the fourth view it is already scrolled

Comment: I got it. I would check it later.

Comment: news about it? I haven't been able to do anything with custom renderers

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue. Check my screenshot. https://imgur.com/WDu28kR I would confirm this issue again.

Comment: exactly. I'm going crazy on it

Comment: I changed because the problem also occurs on android

Comment: I have checked the code on Android 8.0, 9.0, 10.0. It works well. Please check my screenshot: https://imgur.com/b2cANOk Could you provide your device versions for the Android and ios. I am discussing this issue on ios with my colleagues. We need more time and would feedback ASAP.

Comment: Tnk... Android version is 9.0. This the screenshot: https://gifyu.com/image/rGsb

Comment: I double checked with Android 9.0. No errors. According to the screenshot, you used tab? Any changes between the two screenshots you provided?

Comment: No difference. Also in iOS there were tabs and you can see them in the first screenshot on bottom

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue on Android 9.0 with tabs.  The item6 would be scrolled up a little bit. We need more time and would feedback ASAP.

Comment: After recheck by the team, we recommand you to file a bug on GitHub. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for a faster resolution but given the bug I write on the site